# This definitely shouldn't be here

Tags: bug, profile-page, data-explorer, status-completed

[BOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!! http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/3962/editlink.jpg](http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/3962/editlink.jpg)

I'm not ausaitis or a moderator, so I don't think I should be editing his profile...

The link doesn't work, it just sends me to the homepage.

Comment: Does it actually work, or is it false like the old "Clear all associations" button?

Comment: It redirects one to the homepage (as the rights to actually edit are lacking).

Comment: Automatic +1 for freehand circles.

Comment: awesome :) will sort it out today

Answer (score 1):

While it is a bug, clicking the link does **NOT** allow you to edit the profile.